# How to prove the covariance between coefficients in a simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

[image]

How do you get this without using matrix algebra?

Comment: Is this self-study? Please add the tag, if so.

Comment: I would start cranking through the nasty algebra of expanding out everything and seeing where that gets you.

Comment: One approach would be to run your simple regression multiple times using the bootstrap or jacknife, being sure to collect the relevant parameters with each iteration. In this way, you can collect a stack of differing parameters which is readily reducible to a covariance.

Answer (score 1):

First look at
\begin{align*}
\newcommand\sumin{\sum_{i=1}^n}
& Cov\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i y_i,\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}b_i y_i\right)\\
&= Cov\left({a_1y_1+a_2y_2+...+a_ny_n,\sumin b_iy_i}\right)\\
&= Cov\left(a_1y_1,\sumin b_iy_i\right) + Cov\left(a_2y_2,\sumin b_iy_i\right)+...+Cov\left(a_ny_n,\sumin b_iy_i\right)\\
&= a_1Cov\left(y_1, \sumin b_iy_i\right) + a_2Cov\left(y_2, \sumin b_iy_i\right) + ... + a_nCov\left(y_n, \sumin b_iy_i\right)\\
&={a_1Cov(y_1, b_1y_1)} + {a_1Cov(y_1, b_2y_2)} + ... + {a_1Cov(y_1, b_ny_n)} + {a_2Cov(y_2, b_1y_1)} + \\&{a_2Cov(y_2, b_2y_2)} + ...+ a_2Cov(y_2,b_ny_n)+...+a_nCov(y_n, b_ny_n)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_i b_j Cov(y_i, y_j),
\end{align*}
if we suppose $y_i$ are independents then
$Cov(y_i,y_j)=0$ if $i\not=j$, then
$Cov\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i y_i,\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}b_i y_i\right)=\sumin a_ib_iCov(y_i,y_i)=\sumin a_ib_iVar(y_i).$

now calculate covariance betwen $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, we know that are linear combinations of $y_i$, and $y_i$ variance equals to $\sigma^2$. where $c_i= \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\bar{x}(x_i - \bar{x})}{S_{xx}}\right), d_i= \left(\frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{S_{xx}}\right).$
\begin{align*}
&Cov(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta}_1)\\
&=Cov\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} c_{i} y_i, \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} d_{i} y_i\right)\\
&=\sigma^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} c_id_i\\
&=\sigma^2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\bar{x}(x_i - \bar{x})}{S_{xx}}\right) \left(\frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{S_{xx}}\right)\right)\\
&=\sigma^2\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})}{nS_{xx}}- \frac{\bar{x}}{(Sxx)^2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2\right)\\
&=\sigma^2\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}( x_i - \bar{x})}{nS_{xx}} -\frac{\bar{x}}{(Sxx)^2}(S_{xx}) \right)\\
&=\sigma^2 (0- \frac{\bar{x}}{Sxx})
=\sigma^2 \left(- \frac{\bar{x}}{Sxx}\right)=-\sigma^2 \left( \frac{\bar{x}}{Sxx}\right).
\end{align*}
Therefore  $ Cov(\hat{\beta}_0,\hat{\beta_1})=\frac{-\bar{x}\sigma^2}{Sxx}=-\bar{x}Var(\hat{\beta}_1).$